# How can I implement an efficient ticket system in a python based cinema program?

Tags: python

The image below is the tickets that are available in my cinema program, does anyone know the best way of getting a user to input the tickets they require and the number of each ticket. I am completely lost. the only way I can think of is by Asking about each individual ticket but that is inefficient.

```py
("""We have a number of ticket options available
-----------------Tickets-----------------
1) Standard : £10.20
2) Child : £7.70
3) Student : £8.20
4) Senior Ticket (60+) : £6.80
-----------------------------------------""")
Tickets, number = input("Please enter the number corresponding to your ticket choice followed by the number of tickets you would like to purchase: ").split()
choice = input("Would you like to purchase more tickets?" )
if choice == "yes":
   Tickets1 = input("Please enter the number corresponding to your additional ticket choice followed by the number of tickets you would like to purchase: ").split()
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is to collect tuples `(index, count)`, where `index` is ticket number (it can be ticket name, though) and `count` is number of tickets of this type.

Make sure to validate all inputs and just reask if something went wrong.

UPD: you probably should use `while` loop for gathering ticket answers

Answer (score 0):

I would just stick the ticket request logic in a loop that keeps running until the user says they they are finished.  Like so:

```
print("""We have a number of ticket options available
-----------------Tickets-----------------
1) Standard : £10.20
2) Child : £7.70
3) Student : £8.20
4) Senior Ticket (60+) : £6.80
-----------------------------------------""")

def get_ticket_order():
    complete = False
    order = []
    while not complete:
        Tickets, number = input("Please enter the number corresponding to your ticket choice followed by the number of tickets you would like to purchase: ").split()
        order.append((Tickets, number))
        choice = input("Would you like to purchase more tickets?" )
        if choice != "yes":
            complete = True
    return order

order = get_ticket_order()
```

order will end up being a list with multible sublists each having 2 values, 1 for the ticket, and the other for the quantity.  In order to access those, you just need to extract them using indexing or iterate through them with a for loop.  for example:

```
order = [[4,1], [2,2], [3,1]]

for ticket, quantity in order:
    #do something with ticket
    # do something with quantity

# or you can extract them individually with indexes

ticket1, quantity1 = order[0] # ticket1 now = 4 quantity1 now = 1
ticket2, quantity2 = order[1] # ticket2 now = 2 quantity2 now = 2
```

Comment: Hi, I have implemented the code into my project and I am trying to figure out how to pull values out of the array. I have made some alterations so instead of numbers I use the names of the tickets with given values and the program asks for the ticket and the number of tickets in sperate lines

Comment: @ThomasAllen  check out the edit's i made to my answer

Comment: what would you suggest with doing something with the tickets/quantity?

Comment: @ThomasAllen  I don't know what the purpose of the program is. You said you were having problems pulling values out of the array, so I added an example of how to do that.  What you do with those values is up to you.

Comment: i see what you are trying to do but when a user only selects 2 ticket types there is an error message because the index is out of range?

Comment: @ThomasAllen Your question asked for a more efficient way of asking for tickets than asking for each one individually.  That is what my answer addresses.  Beyond that I don't know what you are trying to achieve so I am not sure how I can help you further.

Comment: @ThomasAllen the lower code block in my answer is just an example of how to implement extracting items from the list.  It isn't meant to be pasted into your program